# How to save a PSD as a low size PDF

Tags: pdf, print-to-pdf, psd

i have my CV on a PSD file so when i save it as a PDF the file size is like 55Mb.
so i've tried to save it and open it with Adobe Acrobat to save it again as low size PDF and the file size it's 717Kb

i have tried a second solution, to print it as PDF and the file size this time is 313 Kb.

My problem is how can i make a PDF file with a size of 300Kb in order to upload it on website.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution

> The solution is to save your PSD "for Web or devices" and save it as
>   JPEG image then copy your image Open WinWord and Paste it and finally
>   save your docx file as a PDF file :)

Comment: That may have gotten the job done for you but that's definitely not the best way to do it. You should just mess with the settings when saving as PDF - you have options which will help you cut down on size. Also, PDFs have capabilities like selectable text, which you won't have in an image.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, the size of a PDF is directly related to quality of the picture within it. I'm guessing first program saves from PSD to PDF with best possible quality. You could search for any options that could lower quality, and decide if output was satisfactory.
I'm also using printong to PDF by means of Bullzip PDF or Primo PDF, they both have some means to lower quality upon printing. I guess you just have to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, assuming you're running the full version of Adobe Acrobat is to do character recognition on the document. This generally does a great job of converting the image information into much more compact character information.

Something to watch out for in the original image is to make sure that the document doesn't have any more image information than it needs- is the white page truly white? Use Photoshop 'levels' to make sure the whites are white and the blacks are black. Or use the 'thresholds' command to make everything in the document either black or white- this will allow a huge increase in compressibility...

Answer (score 0):

When saving from Photoshop, select Smallest File Size from your Adobe PDF Presets menu (in the Save As Photoshop PDF dialog). You may also want to check Optimize for Fast Web View. At the tab Compression, under Options, you can change to a lower resolution such as 36 Pixels/inch. That's it.